# Is it possible to attain a reference to the Activity instance which from JNI?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, jnienv

I know that I can attain the Activity object when I call into JNI using the jobject passed into the native method. But, lets assume I cannot use that method to do so.

How can I use the just the JavaVM and JNIEnv objects to attain the Activity instace ?

I know I can use env->FindClass("android/app/Activity") to get to the Activity class, but again, I want the actual Activity instance which initiated my native lib.

Comment: "I want the actual Activity instance which initiated my native lib" it may not have been initiated by an Activity, or at least not by an instance which is still active.  You should probably either pass it in, or see if there is a way at Java-level to discovery the currently active instance, for example in onResume() of each Activity you could set a static global, and query that from jni.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Creating a static reference worked nicely.  I have a getter which I call from native and it worked nicely.  You should form your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.